# Where are the TEXT Tables stored in HSQL DB?

Tags: hsqldb

I just loaded a [TEXT table](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/texttables-chapt.html) to my HSQL Data base, but I can't find it anywhere. I can query it, and it works fine, but I cant find it anywhere. The documentation says [the following](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/texttables-chapt.html)

> With file databases, text fiile locations are restricted to below the 
>       directory that contains the database, unless the textdb.allow_full_path property 
>       is set true as a Java system property. This feature is for security, otherwise 
>       an admin database user may be able to open random files.

What does "*locations are restricted to below the directory*" mean? Where is it?

---

Here are the SQL statements

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE  sal_results 
 (var1 INTEGER,  
 var2 VARCHAR(100) 
 )
 ; 
 SET TABLE sal_results SOURCE "sal_results" ;
```

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for that table.

Comment: I added  the `CREATE` and `SET` statements Thank You

Comment: The data is stored in the file `sal_results` in the same directory that you specified in the connection URL

Comment: My connection URL is: `String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql//localhost";        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");`

Comment: Then it is in the directory that you specified when starting the HSQLDB server.

Comment: I got it. Apparently the above statements do not work when submitting them programmatically. When I use the `Scrapbook` the file does get  created.